# Prometheus "curl" request gives different result from google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, curl, prometheus

I have set up a source of metrics from a job and it is collected with a Prometheus server. The **prometheus.yml** file is

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     1s
  evaluation_interval: 1s

rule_files:
  # - "first.rules"
  # - "second.rules"

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: test_11000
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['0.0.0.0:11000']
  - job_name: prometheus
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']
```

Now, the problem is that the request for the list of jobs is:

```
http://localhost:9090/api/v1/label/job/values
```

But the problem is that putting this link in Google Chrome gets us the correct result, that is:

```
{"status":"success","data":["linera_test_11000","prometheus"]}
```

However, when querying from the command line with curl (I also get this result with Firefox, but I want to use curl) I obtained

```
{"status":"success","data":["prometheus"]}
```

Now, we can extract with "Copy as cURL" from Google Developer pane and this gets us:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/label/job/values' \
  -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8,hr;q=0.7,ru;q=0.6,de;q=0.5,ja;q=0.4,zh-CN;q=0.3,zh;q=0.2' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Cookie: grafana_session_expiry=1702484841; grafana_session=54947f761e264f3789551b790095696d' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: none' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' \
  -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Not_A Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="120", "Google Chrome";v="120"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
    --compressed
```

However, that does not resolve the issue. What could explain the difference in results?

Comment: Your Chrome response references the job as `linera_test_11000` while `prometheus.yml`  defines the job as `test_11000` so is it possible that your results are incorrect? As you hint in your question, it's not possible to get different results from the same endpoint at the same time. So, the possibilities are that (a) Chrome's `localhost` is different from `curl`'s; (b) the queries were run at different times; (c) the queries were run against different configurations (different job names).